# Vue router not rendering components on Firefox

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

```js
const routes = [
    { path: '/', component: ScooterList },
    { path: '/step-2', component: ExtrasList, beforeEnter: PaymentMiddleware.scooterMustSelected },
    { path: '/step-3', component: Payment, beforeEnter: PaymentMiddleware.scooterMustSelected },
]
const router = new VueRouter({
    routes // forma corta para routes: routes
})
```

**On click button**

```js
store.commit('setSelectedScooter', scooter)
this.$router.push('/step-2')
```

The router push works fine in all explorers but not in firefox. The router adds 'step-2' fine in the URL but the components don't change, any idea?

[image]

**EDIT**

https://codesandbox.io/s/n9mynv8rv4

Comment: would you be able to provide a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? jsfiddle demo ?

Comment: Agree with @JacobGoh, provide mvce please! There easiest way is to use https://codesandbox.io as it supports prebuild with webpack

Comment: I'm seeing the component changing as expected in firefox in that codesandbox link you added.

Comment: Yes, me too :'( I'm investigating, I will publish the answer